# Wireguard doesn't connect to internet anymore, any suggestions?

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 23.04, wireguard

I have dual booted my HP OMEN laptop using 2 separate M.2 SSDs, I was on windows and using Wireguard (Tunnel ABC.conf) and left it running and went off to sleep then it shutdown by itself due to low battery, now the next day I directly boot to Ubuntu and try to use wireguard, to my surprise it refuses to give internet access. I logged off Ubuntu and logged into windows which resumed from the state it was previously in, now here I notice internet is not available and tunnel is still active.

Now I can't use Wireguard on both Ubuntu Lunar Lobster and Windows 11 Home Single Language.

Network adapter: Realtek Gaming GbE Family Controller.

I tried reinstalling Wireguard, reinstalling network driver.

Update #1 - Also tried resetting network to factory settings, well it does work for the first try, but if I deactivate tunnel and activate it again same story continues.

Update #2 - Now activating and deactivating the Tunnel ABC.conf really fast can make the tunnel access the internet and now I'm confused, any other tunnel doesn't work at all.